# Bootstrap sidebar affix flickering on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My goal is to have the sidebar affixed, it starts to scroll nicely but when it gets close to the footer it starts to flicker. 
What did I do wrong? 
It seems that the Bootstrap is undecided and keeps toggling `.affix-bottom` on `#sidebar`

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MJMQMr

**JS**

```
var $sidebar = jQuery('#sidebar');

jQuery($sidebar).affix({
  offset: {
    top: $sidebar.offset().top,
    bottom: function() {
      return (this.bottom = jQuery('#footer').outerHeight(true))
    }
  }
})
```

**CSS**

```
.affix {
  top: 0;
}

.affix-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  bottom: 20px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="header">
      <!-- HEADER -->
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="content col-md-8">
        <!-- CONTENT -->
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div id="sidebar">
        <!-- AFFIXED -->
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="footer">
        <!-- FOOTER -->
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I updated my code check now: [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/YorkFord/pen/JyWeYM)

```
#sidebar.affix-bottom {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: can you add more info about what you did to the answer?

Comment: i just put the id="sidebar" on the div with class="col-md-4", check my answer i edited it.